# Basics behind extending jQuery with fn.extend - accessing members

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I made this simple extension of jQuery:

```
 (function($)
    {      
        $.fn.extend({          

            animateleft: function(amount) {              
                    $().animate({
                            left: amount
                            }, 300, function() { }); 

                    return $();    
               }      
         });  
    })(jQuery);
```

I understand that by returning $() it enables chaining. I dont know what exactly is contained in $() however. The animate function doesnt seem to get triggered when I try something like:

```
$('#container').animateleft("+=300");
```

Which I think should work if $('#container') is whats passed in to the extensions as $().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a plugin method, the selected elements are referenced by `this`. So it should be:

```
(function($) {      
    $.fn.extend({          
        animateleft: function(amount) {              
            this.animate({
                left: amount
            }, 300, function() { }); 
            return this;    
        }      
    });  
})(jQuery);
```

`$()` just calls the jQuery function with no parameter, which returns a new (empty) jQuery object.